# Is it possible to merge refiners using a display template

Tags: search, display-template

Let's say I have a set of refiners for "firstname" - among them are two refiners for "Bob" and "Paul".

I know it is possible, using a display template, to rename one of the two to "Bob & Paul" (and remove the other...) but is it also possible to modify the refinement-token so that the refinement would search for "Bob or Paul".

In short: I have this:
[image: Bob and paul in two refiners]
and I'd like to have that: [image: one refiner: "Bob & Paul"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this is impossible using display templates.